# iOS perform action before handling touch events

Tags: objective-c, ios, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm trying to recreate the Facebook slideout menu trick (yes I know there's lots of libraries already).

When a user touches a button on the screen, a new view controller is switched in and a rendered bitmap of the previous screen is shown in the foreground of this new view. The uiimageview has a pan gesture recogniser attached to it to allow it to be moved around on the screen.

Currently it's requiring two touches to activate the gesture recogniser, once to bring in the new view controller, and once for the pan gesture to move the uiimageview.

My question is, on touch down can I bring in the new view controller and then pass the touch events to the uiimageview? Or is there any other trick that will help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't managed to achieve this exactly, but instead I've subclassed UIViewController so the root view controller never changes, just the content that's being displayed.